# How set a vscode contributed setting to be of type color?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a simple VS Code extension which contributes a set of configuration settings. Here's a simplified example of the block from `package.json`:

```
"configuration": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "abc",
    "properties": {
        "xyz": {
            "type": [
                "array"
            ],
            "items": {
                "title": "Custom patterns to highlight.",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "foreground": {
                        "pattern": "^[^$|^\\s]",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "The color.",
                        "description": "The foreground color that will be used for highlighting."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set the type of the `foreground` setting to be color rather than just any string? There doesn't seem to be a color-type or similar.

It would be great if the settings editor could understand that it's a color and show the color picker like in this section:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a format attribute:

```
"myconfig.someColor": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "color-hex",
    "scope": "resource",
    "description": "Some Color"
}
```

I have found some documentation for this:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/json-language-features/server